# Angular2 Promise returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with my Promise. I don't know why but it does return "undefined" in the component after calling my API.

**DeliveryMan:**

```
export class DeliveryMan {
  id: number;
  mail: string;
  passwordToInitialize: boolean;

  name: string;
  administrator: boolean;
}
```

**Component:**

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

    tabDeliveryMan = [];

    constructor(private deliveryManService: DeliveryManService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.deliveryManService.getAll()
          .then((tabDeliveryMan) => {
            this.tabDeliveryMan = tabDeliveryMan,
            console.log(tabDeliveryMan)
        });
    }

    [...]
}
```

**deliveryManService:**

```
export class DeliveryManService {
    getAll(): Promise<DeliveryMan[]> {
      const url = this.apiUrl + 'getAllDeliveryMan';
      return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => response.json() as DeliveryMan[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    [...]
}
```

I get a log undefined but my response isn't null :

```
Response {_body: "[{"id":1,"mail":"antoine@mail.com","password":"89c…ze":true,"name":"antoine","administrator":false}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
```

Comment: It could be that the cast failed and `response.json()` was not possible to convert to `DeliveryMan[]`.

Comment: handleError is executed?

Comment: handleError is not executed. I think it is because my class doesn't correspond. I've added my DeliveryMan class to illustrate it

Comment: Try adding `return` keyword in lambda which returns `response.json()`

Comment: When i replace : "(response) => response.json() as DeliveryMan[]" by "response => response.json()" it work. But why ? The json doesn't really correspond to my class (password/passwordToInitialize), shouldn't i get some error?

Comment: I've noticed in your response that you have this: `"password":"89c…ze":true`. Is this a typo or is it what it's actually being returned? Maybe this is why your cast is not working. And no, you wouldn't get an error when using just `response => response.json()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment i resolved my problem. Replacing this :

```
.then((response) => response.json() as DeliveryMan[])
```

by this

```
response => response.json()
```